# conditions for accessors in Coldfusion ORM

Tags: orm, coldfusion, entity, coldfusion-9, accessor

Once you have loaded a component are you then able to access properties of that object with set conditions? For instance, if you have a one-to-many relationship between people and pets, you load people specifying a particular person, you then want to pull all said persons pets where the pets are of a particular species. cats vs dogs for instance.

```
<cfset person=EntityLoad("person", {name="#URL.name#"})>
<cfset pets=person[1].getPets()>
```

is there anyway to call getPets where type='dog' or something?

Or would I have to loop through the pets creating structures for each type and deal with them that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not loop through the pets if at all possible: distinguishing between types of pets is best left to the object that has a relationship with them or to a service that works with those objects.

One approach is to add a method to `Person` that will return a type of Pet. We're using something similar in our current project.

```
array function getDogs() {
    var HQL = "where petType = 'dog'";
    return ormGetSession().createFilter(this.getPets(),HQL).list();
}
```

You might also be able to make it more generic:

```
array function getPets( required string petType ) {
    var HQL = "where petType = '" & arguments.petType & "'";
    return ormGetSession().createFilter(this.getPets(),HQL).list();
}
```

Another approach is to use the `where` attribute in relationships in the `Person` object when retrieving pets. We use something like this as well:

```
property name="cats" type="array" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="model.Pets" fkcolumn="PERSON_ID" where="PET_TYPE = 'cat'" lazy="false";
property name="dogs" type="array" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="model.Pets" fkcolumn="PERSON_ID" where="PET_TYPE = 'dog'" lazy="false";
```

Note that these examples make several assumptions about the structure of your app and database: there is a Pets object in the `model` folder that maps to a table in your db; this table has a PET_TYPE column (that maps to a petType property) that contains pet types in lower case; the `Person` object maps to a table with a primary key called `PERSON_ID`, which is also a foreign key in the `Pets` table.

Also, when considering these and other approaches, you should think about how you intend to access pets. Turning off lazy loading can create performance hits if you have a significant number of Pets, particularly if there are several types you want to store (so you're making several passes through the Pets table when initializing a Person). You may not need separate properties if you don't access Pets often; it may be enough simply to have a getPets() function.

Comment: Good answer - been stumped on a more efficient way to accomplish this without creating separate relationship properties per condition using WHERE clauses.  Using Hiberate filters seems a pretty elegant solution in the case where all relationship objects are already loaded (e.g. say I want to display each pettype in  separate areas on the same page).