# Global Filtering Across Entities

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

All of my entities contain an `isDeleted` property since we've implemented a "soft delete" on all of our data. I am looking to apply a global filter to the entity so that no matter how it's called, records makred as `isDelete = 0` are the only ones returned.

An example of my Business entity:

```
component persistent="true" table="hier_Businesses" extends="models.BaseEntity" {
    property name="businessID" fieldType="id" generator="increment";
    property name="business" notnull="true";
    property name="businessName" notnull="true";
    property name="isDeleted" ormtype="boolean" default="false";
    property name="businessDisplay" formula="concat(business, ' - ', businessName)";
    property name="centers" singularname="center" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="Center" fkcolumn="businessID" inverse="true" where="isDeleted = 0";

    // validation constraints
    this.constraints = {
        business = {validation = "required,max_length[5]", label = "Business"},
        businessName = {validation = "required,max_length[150]", label = "Business Name"}
    };

    public string function getFullBusinessName() {
        return getValue('businessName', '') & ' (' & getValue('business', '') & ')';
    }
}
```

As you can see, on the `centers` property there is `where="isDeleted = 0"` so that when calling Business.getCenters(), only the active items are returned. This works great for cases where a call to `getCenters()` is made (see [conditions for accessors in Coldfusion ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301745/conditions-for-accessors-in-coldfusion-orm)). However, if querying using HQL such as with **ORMExecuteQuery**, I will need to re-apply those conditions to the joins.

I have also looked at examples of using `ORMGetSession().createFilter(...)`, but the implementation of that doesn't appear to create a global filter on an entity. Some documentation shows modifying the Hibernate mapping XML file, but that's a resource I do not have access to.

Any other suggestions on how this can be obtained?